# MySql Conditional Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by, case-when

Please consider my table (this is just a simplified version, in my project, I got 600,000+ records):

```
Id  TransactionId   TransactionTypeId   Description
1   1               1                   Description1
2   1               1                   Description2
3   1               2                   Description3
4   1               2                   Description4
5   1               1                   Description5
6   1               2                   Description6
7   2               1                   Description7
8   2               1                   Description8
9   2               2                   Description9
10  2               2                   Description10
```

What I need to do is to when `TransactionTypeId = 1`, I need to get the latest data from that table. Otherwise, when `TransactionTypeId <> 1`, I need to get them all.

For this instance, I have this query:

```
SELECT MAX(T.Id)
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T.TransactionId ORDER BY T.Id DESC), ',', 1) AS TransactionId
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T.TransactionTypeId ORDER BY T.Id DESC), ',', 1) AS TransactionTypeId
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T.Description ORDER BY T.Id DESC), ',', 1) AS Description    
FROM Transactions T
GROUP BY T.TransactionId
    , CASE WHEN T.TransactionTypeId = 1 THEN T.TransactionTypeId END
ORDER BY T.TransactionId, T.TransactionTypeId
```

And my desired result would be:

```
Id  TransactionId   TransactionTypeId   Description
5   1               1                   Description5
3   1               2                   Description3
4   1               2                   Description4
6   1               2                   Description6
8   2               1                   Description8
9   2               2                   Description9
10  2               2                   Description10
```

But my problem is, even when `TransactionTypeId <> 1`, the query still groups them.

My query returns:

```
Id  TransactionId   TransactionTypeId   Description
5   1               1                   Description5
6   1               2                   Description6
8   2               1                   Description8
10  2               2                   Description10
```

I know I can use `UNION` here, to seperate queries for the `TransactionTypeId` column, but I can't, it took me more than 5 minutes to get the results. Is there any **possible** (if there's none, I've got no choice but to use `UNION`) way to solve this?

Thanks :)

> UPDATE #1

Here's my query when I'm using `UNION`.

```
SELECT Transaction.Id
    , Transaction.TransactionId
    , Transaction.TransactionTypeId
    , Transaction.Description
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(T.Id)
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T.TransactionId ORDER BY T.Id DESC), ',', 1) AS TransactionId
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T.TransactionTypeId ORDER BY T.Id DESC), ',', 1) AS TransactionTypeId
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T.Description ORDER BY T.Id DESC), ',', 1) AS Description
    FROM Transactions T
    WHERE T.TransactionTypeId = 1
    GROUP BY T.TransactionId

    UNION

    SELECT T.Id
        , T.TransactionId
        , T.TransactionTypeId
        , T.Description
    FROM Transactions T
    WHERE T.TransactionTypeId <> 1
) Transaction
ORDER BY Transaction.TransactionId, Transaction.TransactionTypeId
```

Comment: Post your `UNION` query and the execution plan for it. UNION is a valid solution here and it's probabaly an index issue.

Comment: And you should use `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`

Comment: One more thing: What is the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` for ?

Comment: @ypercube: I'm using `GROUP_CONCAT()`, I need to get the specific data that was concatenated.

Comment: @ypercube: I'll try using `UNION ALL`. Thanks

Comment: How many `TransactionTypeId`s do you have? Just 1 and 2? Do you have an index on `TransactionTypeId`?

Answer (score 5):

TRY WITH THIS

```
    SELECT MAX(T.Id)
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T.TransactionId ORDER BY T.Id DESC), ',', 1) AS TransactionId
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T.TransactionTypeId ORDER BY T.Id DESC), ',', 1) AS TransactionTypeId
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T.Description ORDER BY T.Id DESC), ',', 1) AS Description    
FROM Transactions T
GROUP BY  CASE WHEN T.TransactionTypeId = 1 THEN CONCAT(T.TransactionId,'-',T.TransactionTypeId) ELSE T.Id END
ORDER BY T.TransactionId, T.TransactionTypeId
```

Comment: @great solution munees,u jst rock

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. The only slowing factor I see is the final sorting - so you may try it first without the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT T.Id
    , T.TransactionId
    , 1 AS TransactionTypeId
    , T.Description
FROM Transactions T
  JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id
      FROM Transactions
      WHERE TransactionTypeId = 1
      GROUP BY TransactionId
    ) AS grp
    ON grp.Id = T.Id

UNION ALL

SELECT T.Id
    , T.TransactionId
    , T.TransactionTypeId
    , T.Description
FROM Transactions T
WHERE T.TransactionTypeId <> 1

ORDER BY TransactionId, TransactionTypeId
```

---

You can also use this (which is non `UNION` but has an `OR` so I can't be sure about performance) query:

```
SELECT T.Id
    , T.TransactionId
    , T.TransactionTypeId
    , T.Description
FROM Transactions T
WHERE T.TransactionTypeId <> 1
   OR NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM Transactions tm
        WHERE tm.TransactionTypeId = 1
          AND tm.TransactionId = T.TransactionId
          AND tm.Id > T.Id
      )
ORDER BY T.TransactionId, T.TransactionTypeId
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll get back to this in time. :)